# WCF - Calling WebGet Request From Another Service

Tags: wcf, operationcontract, operationcontext, weboperationcontext

There is a web service I am integrating into. Service asks for an url parameter for redirection after it does its' thing.

I have created a WebGet request like:
`myserviceUrl/redirect/someVal/someOtherVal`
and gave the url to the request as parameter.

Now, when I enter the url into browser (running from VS as localhost), I can confirm that it is working as I intended. But when the address I give as parameter is called from the web service, browser shows a page that says

> Service - Method not allowed.

If I click on address bar and hit enter (with the url which seems to be correct) it works.

What could be the source of this problem, is it a domain, authentication thing?
How can I work around this. Is there a `web.config` setting I can change or some request attribute I should be tinkering with?

I searched the web quite a bit but can't seem to find a solution that works.

**Edit:** (based on oshvartz's comment)

It's a DLL I am calling from my service initialization for testing purposes.

```
public static void AppInitialize()
{
    ServicePostContent con = new ServicePostContent()
    {
        param1 = "val",
        param2 = "val2",
        responseUrl = "myserviceUrl/redirect/someVal/someOtherVal"
    }
    PostResponse res = Service.PostData(con);
}
```

**IService1.cs:**

```
[WebGet (UriTemplate = "redirect/{someVal}/{someOtherVal}")]
[OperationContract] void Test(string someVal, string someOtherVal);
```

**Service1.svc:**

```
public void Test(string someVal, string someOtherVal)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(someVal + " / " + someOtherVal);
}
```

Comment: Please add client code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error, it seems the method you call your rest service is not suitable.
Your service is WebGet, and from your code ServicePostContent, it seems you are using a post method to call the rest service.

Dose your ServicePostContent  use get method to call the rest service?

Or you could change your Webget to WebInvoke and set the Method property to POST

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "redirect/{someVal}/{someOtherVal}", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    [OperationContract] void Test(string someVal, string someOtherVal);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Editing the attributes as you've stated solved the issue. But the thing I find strange is that I can implement a redirect logic inside Test() body and actually get the page redirected. Why I can't do the same with the webget? Is it because the 3rd party service is expecting an end point which will accept post requests only?

Comment: I'm not sure , maybe the ServicePostContent only send a post request, you could use fiddle to find which method of request it sends.